# Add up a points column based on an id from within the same mysql table

Tags: mysql, count, sum

OK the database is layed out as (only columns being used are listed):

```
Table Name: race_stats
Columns: race_id, user_id, points, tournament_id

Table Name: user
Columns: user_id, driver

Table Name: race
Columns: race_id, race_name

Table Name: tournament
Columns: tournament_id, tournament_name
```

This is my current query:

```
$query = "

SELECT user.user_id, user.driver, race_stats.points, race_stats.user_id, 
   SUM(race_stats.points) AS total_points "." 
FROM user, race_stats, tournament, race "." 
WHERE race.race_id=race_stats.race_id 
   AND user.user_id=race_stats.user_id 
   AND tournament.tournament_id=race_stats.tournament_id 
GROUP BY driver 
ORDER BY total_points DESC 
LIMIT 0, 15

";
```

Ok the query works but it is adding them all up for all the available races from the race_stats.race_id column as the total points. I have racked my brain beyond recognition to fix this but I just can't quite seem to find the solution I need. I'm sure it has to be an easy fix but I just can't get it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

///////////////////EDITED WITH RAW VALUES//////////////////////

```
INSERT INTO `race_stats` (`id_race`, `race_id`, `user_id`, `f`, `s`, `race_interval`, `race_laps`, `led`, `points`, `total_points`, `race_status`, `tournament_id`, `driver`, `tournament_name`) VALUES

(1, 1, 4, 1, 4, '135.878', 60, '2', 180, 0, 'Running', 1, 'new_driver_5', ''),
(2, 1, 2, 2, 2, '-0.08', 60, '22', 175, 0, 'Running', 1, 'new_driver_38', ''),
(3, 1, 5, 3, 5, '-11.82', 60, '2', 170, 0, 'Running', 1, 'new_driver_94', ''),
(4, 2, 2, 1, 15, '138.691', 29, '6', 180, 0, 'Running', 2, 'new_driver_38', ''),
(5, 2, 15, 2, 9, '-16.12', 29, '8*', 180, 0, 'Running', 2, 'new_driver_44', ''),
(6, 2, 8, 3, 11, '-2:03.48', 29, '0', 165, 0, 'Running', 2, 'new_driver_83', ''),
```

Let me know if this is what you meant by raw values if not I can get some more data for you.

Comment: can you give some sample data of what you are seeing and what you'd like to see?

Comment: new_driver_83  311
new_driver_5  307 is the output on the webpage but it should be like 180 for driver 83 and 170 for driver 5

Comment: i have no idea what that means. you're going to have to give us some raw data in the same form that it is in the database. edit it into your post.

Comment: To help some more on this I need it to add the points up based on the race_stats.race_id separately instead of adding them all together as one total sum from race_id 1 and 2 in the example above

Comment: does changing your select statement to use group by driver, race_id not work?

Comment: when I do that it gives me a mysql syntax error. I tried it earlier and couldn't resolve why it was giving the error but I thought that would have fixed it

Comment: try this query: SELECT user.driver, race_stats.race_id, SUM(race_stats.points) AS total_points "." 
FROM user, race_stats "." 
WHERE user.user_id=race_stats.user_id 
GROUP BY user.driver, race.race_id

Answer (score 1):

Just posting the solution here for completeness:

```
SELECT user.driver, race_stats.race_id, 
   SUM(race_stats.points) AS total_points "." 
FROM user, race_stats "." 
WHERE user.user_id=race_stats.user_id 
GROUP BY user.driver, race.race_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query you want (formatted for readability):

```
SELECT
    u.driver,
    SUM(rs.points) AS total_points 
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN race_stats rs on rs.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY 1;
```

The advantage of using an outer join (ie `LEFT JOIN`) is that drivers who have no stats still get a row, but with `null` as total_points.

p.s. I don't know what the usage of `"."` in your query is all about, so I removed it.